# What is the type of "ref" in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this code that starts like this

```
  _scrollTo = (ref) => {
    const node = findDOMNode(ref)
```

And then I have this other function that returns

```
  <div ref='entireContainer'>
    blah blah stuff here
  </div>
```

I'm having an issue where I need to pass in the type of ref to the _scrollTo function.  So like if a parameter index were a number we would pass in (index: number).  So I need to pass in (ref: something) instead of just (ref). I don't know what that something is and maybe I'm not phrasing my Google searches well enough to get the answer. Do you know what type it is?

Comment: Do you have the rest of the code for the `_scrollTo` function?  Where do you need to pass in the type?  From the snippet you've provided it looks like you just need to pass in a DOM reference.

Comment: I have another function that returns a jsx element that calls this._scrollTo(this.refs.entireContainer) when it is clicked.

Comment: Post the code, otherwise you're asking me to guess what it does.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what your function `_scrollTo` is doing or where you need to pass the type of `ref` into it, because in the code you've posted it only needs a single parameter.

If the `findDOMNode` function is looking for elements with an attribute `ref` then it's likely the value you need to pass into the function is the string `'entireContainer'`.

If you want to scroll that element into view then here is some appropriate code:

```
var element = document.querySelector("[ref=entireContainer]");
element.scrollIntoView();
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/robertc/aLng6ufd/).

If this is not what you're trying to do then please post more code.